# Time Complexity Comparison between Algorithms built with Python and Java

Tags: python, java, time-complexity

I have recently submitted a paper in a journal. The reviewers have asked to draw a time-complexity comparison between algorithms.

My algorithm was written in python, whereas the algorithms against which the comparison is to be made, are written in Java.

Generally, the algorithms built with Python are slow in my opinion as Java directly runs on the machine. So my algorithm is slower than those.

1. Is my assumption or thought true regarding Python/Java. From random internet threads, it is. However, are there any research references I can cite?
2. How should I build my argument in defense?

Comment: [Time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of an algorithm is language-agnostic. Are you talking about a program's runtime difference between platforms (Python vs Java)?

Comment: Time complexity is determining how the running time of the algorithm changes as the input gets larger.  It has nothing to do with what language it's written in.

Comment: @PatioFurnitureIsCool, Frank Yellin I understand what you are saying. 1) How do you interpret this line: "Can the authors present how the method compares with reference methods in terms of data processing time?" 2) There are 10 other methods. How could I check their time complexity, and what if their papers don't report it?

Answer (score 1):

The reviewers have clearly said that they want ***comparison between time complexity of algorithms***.

1. Algorithms are independent of programming languages and exist on their own. So, I do not think you need to take into consideration the running time of a program in particular language. An algorithm implemented in Python with linear complexity will run leaps and bounds faster than the one written in Java with exponential complexity.
2. You should analyze the approaches taken to solve the problem in both the cases and try to figure out the time and space complexity of them both. And, you should favor the one with less complexity.

This is the point of the whole exercise.

Also, the running time between java and python are very minimal in most of the cases to make any difference.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. 1) How do you interpret this line: "Can the authors present how the method compares with reference methods in terms of data processing time?" 2) There are 10 other methods. How could I check their time complexity, and what if their papers don't report it?

Comment: 1. Data processing time just means the time complexity of the algorithms.
2. It might not be explicitly mentioned on the paper obout the time complexity of the particular algorithm. You should figure out by looking at the code/pseudo code.